# Finding nearest matching points

Tags: r

What I would like to do is for the red points find the nearest equivalent blue dot on the other side of the abline (i.e. 1,5 find 5,1).

[image]

Data:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!Asb7WztvacfOuesIq4evh0jjvejZ4Q

Edit: to open data do `readRDS("path/to/data")`

So what I have tried is to find the difference between the x and y coordinates, rank them and then find the min value going down the ranks for both x and y. The results and pretty bad. The thing I'm struggling with is finding a way to find nearest match of tuples.

My attempt:

```
find_nearest <- function(query, subject){

  weight_df <- data.frame(ID=query$ID)
  #find difference of first, then second, rank and find match in both going from top to bottom
  tmp_df <- query

  for(i in 1:nrow(subject)){
    first_order <- order(abs(query$mean_score_n-subject$mean_score_n[i]))
    second_order <- order(abs(query$mean_score_p-subject$mean_score_p[i]))

    tmp_df$order_1[first_order] <- seq(1, nrow(tmp_df))
    tmp_df$order_2[second_order] <- seq(1, nrow(tmp_df))

    weight_df[,i+1] <- tmp_df$order_1 + tmp_df$order_2

  }
  rownames(weight_df) <- weight_df$ID
  weight_df$ID <- NULL

  print(dim(weight_df))

  nearest_match <- list()
  count <- 1
  subject_ids <- NA
  query_ids <- NA
  while(ncol(weight_df) > 0 & count <= ncol(weight_df)){
    pos <- which(weight_df == min(weight_df, na.rm = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
    if(length(unique(rownames(pos))) > 1){
      for(i in nrow(pos)){
        #if subject/query already used then mask and find another
        if(subject$ID[pos[i,2]] %in% subject_ids){
          weight_df[pos[i,1],pos[i,2]] <- NA
        }else if(query$ID[pos[i,1]] %in% query_ids){
          weight_df[pos[i,1],pos[i,2]] <- NA 
        }else{
          subject_ids <- c(subject_ids, subject$ID[pos[i,2]])
          query_ids <- c(query_ids, query$ID[pos[i,1]])
          nearest_match[[count]] <- data.frame(query=query[pos[i,1],]$ID, subject=subject[pos[i,2],]$ID)
          #mask
          weight_df[pos[i,1],pos[i,2]] <- NA

          count <- count + 1
        }
      }
    }else if(nrow(pos) > 1){
      #if subject/query already used then mask and find another
      if(subject$ID[pos[1,2]] %in% subject_ids){
        weight_df[pos[1,1],pos[1,2]] <- NA
      }else if(query$ID[pos[1,1]] %in% query_ids){
        weight_df[pos[1,1],pos[1,2]] <- NA 
      }else{
        subject_ids <- c(subject_ids, subject$ID[pos[1,1]])
        query_ids <- c(query_ids, query$ID[pos[1,1]])
        nearest_match[[count]] <- data.frame(query=query[pos[1,1],]$ID, subject=subject[pos[1,2],]$ID)
        #mask
        weight_df[pos[1,1],pos[1,2]] <- NA

        count <- count + 1
      }
    }else{
      #if subject/query already used then mask and find another
      if(subject$ID[pos[2]] %in% subject_ids){
        weight_df[pos[1],pos[2]] <- NA
      }else if(query$ID[pos[1]] %in% query_ids){
        weight_df[pos[1],pos[2]] <- NA 
      }else{
        subject_ids <- c(subject_ids, subject$ID[pos[2]])
        query_ids <- c(query_ids, query$ID[pos[1]])
        nearest_match[[count]] <- data.frame(query=query[pos[1],]$ID, subject=subject[pos[2],]$ID)
        #mask
        weight_df[pos[1],pos[2]] <- NA

        count <- count + 1
      }
    }
  }

  out <- plyr::ldply(nearest_match, rbind)

  out <- merge(out, data.frame(subject=subject$ID, 
                                 mean_score_p_n=subject$mean_score_p, 
                                 mean_score_n_n= subject$mean_score_n), by="subject", all.x=TRUE)

  out <- merge(out, data.frame(query=query$ID, 
                                 mean_score_p_p=query$mean_score_p, 
                                 mean_score_n_p= query$mean_score_n), by="query", all.x=TRUE)


  return(out)

}
```

Edit: is this what the solution looks like for you?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=B[out,], aes(x=mean_score_p, y= mean_score_n, color="red")) +
  geom_point(data=A, aes(x=mean_score_p, y=mean_score_n, color="blue")) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

```
query <- readRDS("query.dms")
subject <- readRDS("subject.dms")
kA <- nrow(subject)
kB <- nrow(query)
A <- as.matrix(subject[, 2:3])
B <- as.matrix(query[, 2:3])
```

where we want to find the closest "reverse" point (row) in `B` to each point in `A`.

**Solution permitting non-unique results**

Then, assuming that you are using the Euclidean distance,

```
D <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(A, B[, 2:1])))[(1 + kA):(kA + kB), 1:kA]
unname(apply(D, 2, which.min))
#  [1] 268 183 350 284  21 360 132 287 100 298  58  56 170  70  47 305 353
# [18]  43 266 198  58 215 198 389 412 321 255 181  79 340 292 268 198  54
# [35] 390  38 376  47  19  94 244  18 168 201 160 194 114 247 287 273 182
# [52]  87  94  87 192  63 160 244 101 298  62
```

are the corresponding row numbers in `B`. The trick was to switch the coordinates of the points in `B` by using `B[, 2:1]`.

**Solution with unique results**

```
out <- vector("numeric", length = kA)
colnames(D) <- 1:ncol(D)
rownames(D) <- 1:nrow(D)
while(any(out == 0))
  for(i in 1:nrow(D)) {
    aux <- apply(D, 2, which.min)
    if(i %in% aux) {
      win <- which(aux == i)[which.min(D[i, aux == i])]
      out[as.numeric(names(win))] <- as.numeric(rownames(D)[i])
      D <- D[-i, -win, drop = FALSE]
    }
  }
out
#  [1] 268 183 350 284  21 360 132 213 100 298  22  56 170  70 128 305 353
# [18]  43 266 198  58 215 294 389 412 321 255 181  79 340 292  20 347  54
# [35] 390  38 376  47  19  94  73  18 168 201 160 194 114 247 287 273 182
# [52]  87 365 158 192  63 211 244 101  68  62
```

whereas

```
all(table(res) == 1)
# [1] TRUE
```

confirms uniqueness. The solution is not the most efficient, but on your dataset it takes only a couple of seconds. It takes some time because it keeps going over all the available points in `B` checking if it is the closest one to any of the points in `A`. If so, the corresponding point in `B` is assigned to the closest one in `A`. Then both the point in `A` and the point in `B` are eliminated from the distance matrix. The loop goes until every point in `A` has some match in `B`.

Comment: I have made an edit on how to read the data. Using Euclidean distance is the way to go I think. But one thing I was trying to avoid is to have duplicate points assigned. So in the end I want `nrow(A)` equivalent points matched in `B`.

Comment: If B1 is the closest one for points A1 and A2, I suppose B1 should be assigned to the one that is closer, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If B1 is the same distance from A1, A2, then I guess one solution would be random assignment, but an ideal solution would be to look at the second closest B2 and B3 and which ever one is closest (B2 from A1 vs B3 from A2; lets say its B3 and A2) then assign B3 to A2 and B1 to A1.

Comment: In the end what i want to achieve is a comparison of the features of the red points with the blue points, perhaps do some stats. I'm wondering whether a distribution matched selection would be more suitable.

Comment: I assumed that the nature of your data is such that there cannot be same distances. What I had in mind is that, as in my current solution, B20 is the closest point to three points in A. Then, since B20 has to be assigned to only one of them, we should assign it to the one that is closest to B20.

Comment: I just had a look into the distance matrix, I see what you mean, yes that could work as long as there isn't a tie in a larger dataset.

Comment: I made an edit with what the solution looks like. Does it look the same for you? I was imagining the blue points would be more dispersed making a mirror image of the red.

Comment: Now it looks good. The problem was that `A` and `B` were data frames with column names and `B[, 2:1]`then doesn't really reverse the coordinates.. So it was just matching `A` with `B` rather than `B[, 2:1]`.